# Algorithm to sort documents physically java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have a scanner that captures account numbers from a couple of documents. I need an algorithm that sorts these documents physically. The scanner has 11 pockets used to be separated. I tried some (Merge sort, Bucket sort) but not how a fixed number of pockets. My solution so far is that I do one pass of all documents, which serve to recognize the entire universe. I also acknowledge that I have to pass several times all documents through the scanner to be sorted physically. Any doubt I can answer those. If possible in java.

Comment: So you have a device that you can program that will read a number and decide which pocket to put the paper in?

Comment: You need to tell us exactly how this is going to work. What is the result that you want? What are keys on the documents? How do they correspond to the buckets?

Comment: I need that the documents are sorted physically occupying the 11 pockets. The data I have is an array of integers with the numbers of documents. No matter how many documents fall into each pocket. Only they are ordered.

Answer (score 3):

Shades of 1965!

When I was in school in the early 1970's we had to submit programs on punched cards, and for that purpose there was a room full of card punches.  In one corner was a card sorter, a behemoth about 10 feet long, 4 feet tall and 3 feet wide. It had 12 output bins, and on each pass would divide the cards into bins based on the value in a single column.

To sort a card deck it had to have sequence numbers punched into each card at a fixed location, usually columns 73-80.  You would run the deck through the sorter multiple times, starting with the LAST column (80) first; this pass divided the cards into 10 stacks, each containing cards whose sequence numbers ended with a specific digit.  Then you took the 10 stacks and combined them in order into one, changed the sorter setting to column 79, and ran them through again.  Then you would repeat this until you reached column 73 (or the first column containing only zeroes).

You should be able to do exactly the same thing with your scanner.

(Wow, I never thought that little bit of historical arcana would EVER be useful :-)

Comment: +1, mainly for making me glad that I'm too young to ever have had to deal with that s\*\*\*.